# Compilation error, "uses undefined struct"

Tags: c++, struct

I want to forward-declare the parts of a struct, so the "package" struct is first shown. I'm getting an error of "use of undefined struct" where "Header" is declared in "Package". Surely the compiler (VS2010) would scan the header file for the definition before throwing this error?

```
struct Header;

struct Package
{
    Header header;             <-- "uses undefined struct"

};

struct Header
{
    uint32_t Signature;
    uint8_t MajorVersion;
    uint8_t MinorVersion;
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm getting an error of "use of undefined struct" where "Header" is declared in "Package".

You can't declare a member of an *incomplete type*, because the compiler doesn't know how big it is and how much space should it reserve for it (among other things).

> Surely the compiler (VS2010) would scan the header file for the definition before throwing this error?

No, what makes you think that?

Comment: Just for completeness: while you cannot make member of incomplete type, you can make a pointer to it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the type until it has been fully declared, since information such as the size etc. needs to be known beforehand. You can, however, make pointers to these types, since they do not require this information.

---

There are two ways to resolve this. A cheaty one and a "proper" one.

First the cheaty one. You can prototype a struct, however, you can only use the struct as a pointer until you declare it. So you cannot use `Header` as a value type before it has been declared. So the cheaty way would be replacing `Header header;` with `Header *header;` and then allocate memory at runtime.

There is, however, a much, much nicer way.

You could split this single file into multiple files, namely: `header.hpp` and `package.hpp`, and have them include eachother. However, there is one problem when doing this. When the headers recursively include eachother (or you include the same header multiple times), the types will be redifined over and over again. You need a way to only define the types once. This is done almost every time a header is used, by enclosing it with "inclusion guards". It looks like so:

```
#ifndef HEADER_HPP
#define HEADER_HPP

// Header code here

#endif /* HEADER_HPP */
```

That way, they'll only be declared once, but you can use both types in both files.

So your `package.hpp` file will look like this:

```
#ifndef PACKAGE_HPP
#define PACKAGE_HPP

#include "header.hpp"

struct Package {
    Header header;
};

#endif
```

And your `header.hpp` will look like this:

```
#ifndef HEADER_HPP
#define HEADER_HPP

struct Header {
    uint32_t Signature;
    uint8_t MajorVersion;
    uint8_t MinorVersion;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have Package contain something of type Header when the compiler doesn't yet know what exactly Header is. You can only have pointers to Header.

Comment: @Baltasarq: Mainly because we are still using the outdated _inclusion model_ inherited from _C_, but there are other reasons as well.

Comment: Certainly, @K-Ballo, but the "classic" C++ compiler could be substituted by a modern compiler, and then ignore #include's. I mean, a modern version could be designed, even with backwards compatibility in mind.

Comment: The CLang team are working on an 'import' statement for C. See http://llvm.org/devmtg/2012-11/Gregor-Modules.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointers:

```
struct Package
{
    struct Header *header;
};

struct Header
{
    uint32_t Signature;
    uint8_t MajorVersion;
    uint8_t MinorVersion;
};
```